# can we write rules for Cryptographic function

Tags: math, prolog

Can we write cryptographic function as rule in prolog i.e.

```
C = enc(K, M).
M = dec(K, C).
```

I don't want low level detail but want to write a functor which provide me this functionality. If it is not possible in prolog then can some one give me reasoning behind that due to this reason prolog doesn't support this kind of functions.

Answer (score 4):

In ISO standard Prolog I don't believe you can, but SWI-Prolog has an [extension](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.26%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/extendarith.html%27%29%29) that allows this. If you define predicates

```
enc(K, M, Result) :- % whatever
dev(K, C, Result) :- % whatever
```

that return a result in their third argument, you can say

```
:- arithmetic_function(enc/2).
:- arithmetic_function(dec/2).
```

and use those with

```
C is enc(K, M).
```

etc. You can't do this with `=`, because that has a special meaning in Prolog: unification of the variable `C` with the term (data structure) `enc(K,M)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about functors, and prolog did't know about them too. 
You may use only predicates - facts, witch connect some variables.

For example

```
encode(+Key, +Message, -CodeMessage)/3
decode(+Key, +CodeMessage, -OriginalMessage)/3
```

It means, that only if you know key and message you could get code of this message with encode/3 predicate. And only if you know key and code of the message you could get the original message with decode/3 predicate.

Comment: A *functor* is the head of a term (so in `f(X,Y,Z)`, `f` is the functor). Also, facts are not the same as predicates.